# Characterizing the exponential savings in active learning

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, vc-dimension

Let $H$ be a hypothesis class with VC dimension $d$. In supervised learning, we need almost $O(\frac{d}{\epsilon})$ random labelled examples to return a hypothesis within $\epsilon$ from the target (separable case).

[Active learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)) potential lies in its exponential saving in terms of the number of queries required compared to the supervised learning. This big saving in known for some structures ( for example learning threshold functions requires $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ examples while we can achieve the same goal with $log \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ in active learning ).

What characterizes this exponential reduction in general? Are there certain properties such that if $H$ satisfies them then active learning would help?

Comment: The $O(d/\epsilon)$ isn't quite right, unless it's hiding log factors...

Answer (score 1):

See Hanneke's disagreement coefficient,
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1291388378

Comment: It would be great if you (or someone else) can expand the answer a bit with a summmary of what the disagreement coefficient is and in what sense it captures learning rates in active learning (especially when compared to passive learning).

Comment: Oh wow, it's been a while! Maybe Steve will run across this question and rise to the challenge... :)